# how to convert unix timestamp to oracle DATE

Tags: java, sql, oracle, unix, timestamp

I have a date type in oracle and i want insert unix timestamp  data into it.

I use this SQL query in PL/SQL which works.

```
select TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd') + 1413360712/86400 +TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TZ_OFFSET(sessiontimezone),1,3))/24 from dual;
```

the output is right.

`2014/10/15 16:11:52`

But when i use it in java, the output is different.

```
            String sql = "insert into appliance_application (id, emp_id, typeid, num, spec, action, actiontime, oper_id) VALUES(applianceapplication_seq.nextval, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd') + 1413360712/86400 +TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TZ_OFFSET(sessiontimezone),1,3))/24, ?)";
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++){
                Itembean ib = (Itembean)list.get(i);
                pstmt.setObject(1, ib.getEmpid());
...   



                pstmt.setObject(5, ib.getAction());
//              pstmt.setLong(6, ib.getActiontime());
//              pstmt.setObject(7, ib.getOper_id());
                pstmt.setObject(6, ib.getOper_id());
                log.info(ib.getActiontime()+ "....");

                pstmt.addBatch();
            }

...
```

I check the inserted data and find output is wrong.

`2014/10/15 8:11:52`

my sessiontimezone is +8.
what's wrong?

Comment: Are you certain that the `sessiontimezone` of the Java session is actually +8?  I would wager that the Java app server's locale is setting the session time zone to GMT.

Comment: So it's about Java session timezone. I use tomcat 7 on windows. I don't know where to add `-Duser.timezone=GMT+08` in catalina.bat.

Comment: I search many but none works. In `TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd') + 1413360712/86400 +TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TZ_OFFSET(sessiontimezone),1,3))/24, ?)`, sessiontimezone does not work. I think it runs on oracle, I don't understand why.At last I add 8/24, it's not a good solution.Thanks  @JustinCave

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public Timestamp parseDateToTimestamp(java.util.Date inDate)
{
    if (inDate == null)
        return null;

    return new java.sql.Timestamp(inDate.getTime());
}
```